# (Java, Netbeans) Trouble trying to read a txt file with a scanner?

Tags: java, file, netbeans, java.util.scanner

I am supposed to write an assignment that solves a 5 by 5 board of numbers. The program has to read in a file of these numbers, and what I am trying to do is read the values in the file (they have spaces in between, which I don't want), save all the values in a 1D array, and then fill my 2D array board with the data. But I can't even get the file to read even though I am sure I did everything properly.

I am positive I am supposed to put the txt file with the src folder as I have nearly the exact same code and file placement for another program that reads a file and it works.

Here is my code.

```
static String[][] board = new String[5][5];
static String[] data = new String[25];

public static void fillBoard(String filename) throws Exception {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(filename));

    while (scanner.hasNextLine() && !isFull(data)) {
        String currentLine = scanner.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            data = currentLine.split("[ ]");
        }
    }
}

public static boolean isFull(String data[]) {
    boolean toReturn = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i] != null) {
            toReturn = true;
        } else {
            toReturn = false;
        }
    }
    return toReturn;
}

public static void printData(String data[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(data[i]);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try {
        fillBoard("testboard2.txt");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Cannot find the specified file.");
    }
    printData(data);
}
```

And this is what it prints out:

run:
Cannot find the specified file.
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

I don't know what could be wrong, but it need to work in order for me to do anything else. The debugger helped very little.

Comment: are you providing your `filename` along with correct extension ?

Comment: Catching `Exception` in `main()` is very bad practice. You should remove that try-catch and the `throws` statement for `fillBoard()`. That way you'll get a more specific error message, which makes it easier to solve the problem

Comment: Thanks for you comment. My problem ended up being the placement of the file after all though - which is surprising but at least I found the solution. I guess my code was fine. It's nice to know what is a good practice or not. I have only taken two semesters of Java so I still have much to learn.